# Create a sparse matrix from lines of entries in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have a dataframe in R of the following form:

```
                     lemma       mi                                 doc
1        butroe_polihalino 5.385031 ANEJO_05_Q ECOL_Cantabrico Oriental
2        tramo_oligohalino 5.385031 ANEJO_05_Q ECOL_Cantabrico Oriental
3 programas_de_seguimiento 5.385031 ANEJO_05_Q ECOL_Cantabrico Oriental
4                     ifim 5.385031 ANEJO_05_Q ECOL_Cantabrico Oriental
5                      rdl 5.385031 ANEJO_05_Q ECOL_Cantabrico Oriental
6                 prointec 5.385031 ANEJO_05_Q ECOL_Cantabrico Oriental
```

And I want to create a sparse matrix (in which I'll run PCA) of the form:

```
                butroe_polihalino tramo_oligohalino ...
ANEJO_05_...    5.385031          5.385031
docs2           (no value)        4.321345
...
```

Which basically contains docs as rows, lemmas as columns and the mi is the value. Also it is possible to have not defined values.

Is there any way of defining a sparse matrix like that in R from the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends how you want to deal with the cases where there are combinations of values in `lemma` and `doc` that do not appear. You mention they are "not defined" and suggest "(no value)" to appear in the answer.

Here is a more complete toy example:

```
set.seed(1)
(dfr <- data.frame(lemma = rep(c("foo", "bar", "baz"), each = 2),
           mi = runif(6),
           doc = rep(c("mary", "jane", "mary", "bruce", "dolly", "zizz")),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
#>   lemma        mi   doc
#> 1   foo 0.2655087  mary
#> 2   foo 0.3721239  jane
#> 3   bar 0.5728534  mary
#> 4   bar 0.9082078 bruce
#> 5   baz 0.2016819 dolly
#> 6   baz 0.8983897  zizz
```

If it makes sense for the number `0` to appear in such cases you can just use `xtabs` as follows:

```
xtabs(mi ~ lemma + doc, dfr, sparse = TRUE)

#> 3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#>      doc
#> lemma     bruce     dolly      jane      mary      zizz
#>   bar 0.9082078 .         .         0.5728534 .        
#>   baz .         0.2016819 .         .         0.8983897
#>   foo .         .         0.3721239 0.2655087 .
```

If you want the values to be missing in the sense of `NA` then this is the best I can do, using `tapply`:

```
Matrix::Matrix(with(dfr, tapply(mi, list(lemma, doc), sum), sparse = TRUE))

#> 3 x 5 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
#>         bruce     dolly      jane      mary      zizz
#> bar 0.9082078        NA        NA 0.5728534        NA
#> baz        NA 0.2016819        NA        NA 0.8983897
#> foo        NA        NA 0.3721239 0.2655087        NA
```

which explicitly makes it a sparse matrix using `Matrix::Matrix`.

Bear in mind that sparse matrices are useful when they are big and don't have many non-zero entries, and that `NA` is *not* 0.

Comment: Worked completely fine, thanks! Using number 0 for not defined values is completely fine for my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sparseMatrix` from the base `matrix` package. (assuming you do not have factors in your data.frame.)

```
m <- Matrix::sparseMatrix(i = match(df$doc, unique(df$doc)), 
                          j = match(df$lemma, unique(df$lemma)), 
                          x = df$mi,
                          dimnames = list(unique(df$doc), unique(df$lemma)))
```

or `caste_sparse` from `tidytext`. This is less typing and the function does some checks if your data has factors or not.

```
m <- tidytext::cast_sparse(df, row = doc, column = lemma, value = mi)
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(lemma = c("butroe_polihalino", "tramo_oligohalino", "programas_de_seguimiento", 
                               "ifim", "rdl", "prointec"), 
                     mi = c(5.385031,5.385031, 5.385031, 5.385031, 5.385031, 5.385031), 
                     doc = c("ANEJO_05_Q ECOL_Cantabrico Oriental","ANEJO_05_Q ECOL_Cantabrico Oriental", 
                             "ANEJO_05_Q ECOL_Cantabrico Oriental", "ANEJO_05_Q ECOL_Cantabrico Oriental", 
                             "ANEJO_05_Q ECOL_Cantabrico Oriental", "ANEJO_05_Q ECOL_Cantabrico Oriental")), 
                .Names = c("lemma", "mi", "doc"), 
                class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```